# Javascript Pig UDF seems to return nothing

Tags: javascript, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I have a JS udf that looks as so:

```
is_match.outputSchema = 'matched:chararray, match_against:chararray, match_candidate:chararray';
function is_match (match_against, match_candidate) {
    var mre = new RegExp(match_against);
    return { word:mre.test(match_candidate), word:match_against, word:match_candidate };
}
```

The Pig that calls it looks like such:

```
register '<full path omitted>my_match.js' using javascript as js_match;

regexes = load <stuff> using PigStorage() as ( regex:chararray );
tests   = load <stuff> using PigStorage() as ( agent:chararray );

regexes = distinct regexes;
tests = distinct tests;

tests = cross regexes, tests;

matched = foreach tests generate js_match.is_match( regex, agent );
```

What I get is a ton of empty tuples:

```
((,,))
((,,))
((,,))
((,,))
```

If I switch the function in JS to look like so:

```
is_match.outputSchema = 'foo:int';
function is_match (foo, bar) {
    return 1;
}
```

I actually get:

```
(1.0)
(1.0)
(1.0)
```

which is what I expect. However, when I change the return from JS to return any of my actual data, it won't. If I make the return statement `'return 1;'`, I get the 1's.

I am not sure why I am unable to return values from the larger JS function and I am able to return less complex data that "comes through." It should be returning "something" each and every time. For our purposes, `tests` looks like:

```
(.oo,foobar)
(.oo,bazfoobar)
(.oo,foobarbaz)
([Ff]oo,Bar)
([Ff]oo,bar)
```

where the first column is an expression, and the second column is a string. I'm just trying to run through a giant list of strings with a giant list of expressions.

Comment: What happen when you set `is_match.outputSchema` to `T: (matched:chararray, match_against:chararray, match_candidate:chararray)`.  It looks like you are trying to return a tuple and your output schema does not match it.

Comment: Hi, I did switch to what you indicate there, and my return records changed from `((,,))` to `()`. I admit I am a bit mystified.